# Serializer is trying to serialize a property decorated with [ProtoIgnore]

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protobuf-net

I have the following class

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]
public class Foo
{
    public int foo { get; set; }

    [ProtoIgnore]
    public Bar bar { get; set; }

    public int ToMD5Hash()
    {
        var md5 = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<Foo>(ms, this);
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(ms.ToArray());
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(hash, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting an exception when calling ToMD5Hash. It says `No serializer defined for type: SomeNamespace.Bar` even if the property is decorated with the ProtoIgnore attribute.

Note: If I remove ImplicitFields and use ProtoMember, the serialization works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to use `[NonSerialized]`, it should be [supported](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual) too. And I got feeling `[ProtoIgnore]` is field-only attribute, right?

Comment: Field and properties. I'll give it a try but I would be very surprised if it made any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've told it to serialize the **fields**. The field is not decorated with `[ProtoIgnore]`. The *property* is, and there is no good way to equate fields to properties. The use of the term "fields" here is very specific and intentional: it doesn't mean "members" - it means "fields".

Options:

- tell it to serialize public members, not fields
- use a manually implemented property and mark the *field* with `[ProtoIgnore]`
- mark the members manually

It would be *nice* if automatically implemented properties allowed the same syntax as field-like events, i.e.

```
[field:ProtoIgnore]
public int Foo {get;set;}
```

However, I'm pretty sure that this is not supported in the language.

Comment: After hours, I find your answer. thank you so much.